# rsync or scp only if there's a difference

Tags: debian, backup, rsync, scp

How do i figure out if there's a difference between an backupfile and the current used one.
The Filename of the Backup is named like: filename_date.conf
and the currend used one is name like: filename.conf
I only need to know if the content is the same or not!

I know how to copy the files and rename it like i wish, but i don't know how to figure out if there's a content difference.

Comment: You could write a script which compare files by the SHA1 checksum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use md5sum.

You can md5 remote files though ssh, like

```
ssh user@host md5sum filename_date.conf
```

then you can md5sum the local file and compare those.

Comment: NB: sha1 is more robust, particularly if you're concerned about intentional md5 collisions. Which are now pretty easy to engineer, if your process is open to external influence:  https://lwn.net/Articles/139923/

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with Stone's excellent answer (+1!), but since you ask about `rsync`, you might want to investigate the `-c` flag, which tells `rsync` to perform a checksum (MD4, as it happens) to assist in deciding if a file has been modified, before deciding whether or not to transfer it.

Comment: thank you too, i'd have to use scp because with this date in the filename it i wouldn't be able to automize it with rsync.
Maybe i'll try this after vacation :)

Answer (score 2):

`rsync` already has a lot of mechanisms to check for differences.  If you aren't renaming files `rsync` won't transfer unchanged files.

I have used `rsync` to minimize transfer for open log files by only transferring the new data.  The `man` documentation discusses your various options.

Tools like `backuppc` and `Unison` use the `rsync` protocol and capabilities to minimized data transfer.